# Mongodb : Connecting to a user with password when tls is enabled

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, debian

I'm setting a replica set on 3 mongodb instances on debian 9 and I enabled TLS authentication for the replica set members. Here's the configuration :

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
    clusterAuthMode: x509
net:
   tls:
      mode: requireTLS
      certificateKeyFile: crt-key.pem
      CAFile: chain.crt
      clusterFile: crt-key.pem
      certificateKeyFilePassword: XXXXXX
      clusterPassword: XXXXXX
      allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true

replication:
   replSetName: "my-replica-set"
```

The replication works fine but I can't connect with a username/password to the database :

```
mongosh --port 27017  --authenticationDatabase "admin" -u "user" -p 
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 127.0.0.1:27017 closed
```

Here's the log :

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-30T18:02:07.696+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22988,   "ctx":"conn30","msg":"Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":141,"codeName":"SSLHandshakeFailed","errmsg":"The server is configured to only allow SSL connections"},"remote":"127.0.0.1:46486","connectionId":30}}
```

Comment: as I see you don't pass `tls` argument to mongosh, For legacy shell you could set this argument like: `mongo --tls`, I assume that mongosh has the same argument

Comment: totally ot, but you shoud seriously consider updating to a newer Debian version (the current version is Debian11). stretch (aka Debian 9) has seen EOL in 2020, the long-term support will end by the end of june 2022 (that is: in 30 days). Debian has excellent upgrading support (unlike other distros like Ubuntu)

Comment: tls argument asks for a certificate chain which is not what i'm trying to do actually. Certificates are only used for the replication, the users should connect with login/password if possible.
I will look into upgrading all Debian on my infrastructure, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
net:
   tls:
      certificateKeyFile: crt-key.pem
      clusterFile: crt-key.pem
```

is redundant. If `clusterFile` is not provided then `certificateKeyFile` is used. So, you can simply use

```
net:
   tls:
      mode: requireTLS
      certificateKeyFile: crt-key.pem
      CAFile: chain.crt
      certificateKeyFilePassword: XXXXXX
      allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true
```

`mode: requireTLS` means, client **and** replicaset members have to use TLS/SSL, thus you must enable TLS/SSL also for client.

You need to specify tls option:

```
mongosh --tls --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase "admin" -u "user" -p
```

Depending on your openssl library version, you may also have to specify the CA-File, i.e.

```
mongosh --tls --tlsCAFile "chain.crt" --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase "admin" -u "user" -p
```

If you like to enable TLS/SSL only for replicaset members, then use

```
net:
   tls:
      mode: preferTLS
```

Now, you can connect with

```
mongosh --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase "admin" -u "user" -p
```

Note, depending on your CA this setup can be security risk. If `chain.crt` is your own CA protected with your secret private key, then you are on the safe side. However, `chain.crt` also could be a company wide, commonly used CA. In this case an attacker only needs to create an arbitrary certificate where the Organization attributes (O's), the Organizational Unit attributes (OU's), and the Domain Components (DC's) matches the `crt-key.pem` and which is accepted by `chain.crt` (which could be done by a simple ticket to your IT department).

Organization attributes (O's), the Organizational Unit attributes (OU's), and the Domain Components (DC's)  of `crt-key.pem` server certificate you get simply by

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <hostname>:27017
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'd like to use certificate authentication only for the replication. Users should only need a password to connect in order to avoid big changes on production. I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Yes, that should be provided with your current config file. Replication set members are authenticated by x509 certificate, normal users are authenticated by username/password (or by x509 certificate, provided you created the user according to [Add x.509 Certificate subject as a User](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/#add-x-509-certificate-subject-as-a-user))

Comment: I don't get why it does not work then. I tried to connect with the command you provided. I get :

`MongoServerSelectionError: self signed certificate in certificate chain`


and this in the log :
`{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-31T14:39:25.962+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23234,   "ctx":"conn12","msg":"No SSL certificate provided by peer"}`

Comment: Maybe try with `preferTLS`

Comment: Please see my update